# What hook should I use for org-roam when there is a creation/renaming of roam node

Tags: org-mode, hooks, org-roam

I wrote a function that will update my roam notes `.gitignore`.
I would like to call this function whenever there is a creation or renaming of roam node. What hook should I be using?

Comment: What does `.gitignore' have to do with `org-roam'?

Comment: There are some org-roam notes that carry a particular file tag that I would like to be git ignored, I wrote a function to retrieve all org-roam files with that file-tag, and write that list to `.gitignore`, I do source control of my org-roam notes because I don't have access to internet accross my machines

Comment: Why didn't you add all that to the question? How do you expect people to figure that out if you don't tell them? Please take your comment and *add it to the question*.

Comment: @NickD I don't think it's necessary for the answer I'm seeking

Comment: Then why did you add that detail? If it is not relevant, take it out.

Answer (score 1):

`find-file-hook`, `advice` on `rename-file` and `delete-file`.

Here is the source code of `org-roam-db-autosync-mode` you can refer to:

```lisp
(define-minor-mode org-roam-db-autosync-mode
  "Global minor mode to keep your Org-roam session automatically synchronized.
Through the session this will continue to setup your
buffers (that are Org-roam file visiting), keep track of the
related changes, maintain cache consistency and incrementally
update the currently active database.

If you need to manually trigger resync of the currently active
database, see `org-roam-db-sync' command."
  :group 'org-roam
  :global t
  :init-value nil
  (let ((enabled org-roam-db-autosync-mode))
    (cond
     (enabled
      (add-hook 'find-file-hook  #'org-roam-db-autosync--setup-file-h)
      (add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook #'org-roam-db--close-all)
      (advice-add #'rename-file :after  #'org-roam-db-autosync--rename-file-a)
      (advice-add #'delete-file :before #'org-roam-db-autosync--delete-file-a)
      (org-roam-db-sync))
     (t
      (remove-hook 'find-file-hook  #'org-roam-db-autosync--setup-file-h)
      (remove-hook 'kill-emacs-hook #'org-roam-db--close-all)
      (advice-remove #'rename-file #'org-roam-db-autosync--rename-file-a)
      (advice-remove #'delete-file #'org-roam-db-autosync--delete-file-a)
      (org-roam-db--close-all)
      ;; Disable local hooks for all org-roam buffers
      (dolist (buf (org-roam-buffer-list))
        (with-current-buffer buf
          (remove-hook 'after-save-hook #'org-roam-db-autosync--try-update-on-save-h t)))))))
```

Comment: I am confused by the question, but you seem not to be. So how does this answer the question?

Comment: @NickD Hi, I don't particularly understand why he needs to update `.gitignore` either, but back to his question about how to execute certain functions when creating and renaming org roam nodes.

Comment: @TianshuWang Thanks for the quick reply, I was just wondering if org-roam should have a dedicated hook for this

Comment: @Tian Not, as the aboving code are copied from org-roam

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer given by @TianshuWang, I came up with the following function (requires lexical binding).

```
;;; -*- lexical-binding:t; -*-
(defun add-to-roam-file-hooks (FUNCTION)
  "Adds function to crud event hooks for org roam files only"

  ;; for file saving
  (advice-add
   #'org-roam-db-autosync--setup-file-h :after
   (lambda ()
     (add-hook 'after-save-hook
      (lambda ()
    (when org-roam-db-update-on-save
      (funcall FUNCTION))))
     nil t))

  ;; for file renaming
  (advice-add
   #'org-roam-db-autosync--rename-file-a :after
   (lambda (old-file new-file-or-dir &rest _args)
     (let ((new-file (if (directory-name-p new-file-or-dir)
             (expand-file-name (file-name-nondirectory old-file) new-file-or-dir)
               new-file-or-dir)))
       (setq new-file (expand-file-name new-file))
       (when (org-roam-file-p new-file)
     (funcall FUNCTION)))))

  ;; for file deleting
  (advice-add
   #'org-roam-db-autosync--delete-file-a :before
   (lambda (file &optional _trash)
     (when (and (not (auto-save-file-name-p file))
        (not (backup-file-name-p file))
        (org-roam-file-p file))
       (funcall FUNCTION))))
  )
```

To use it, evaluate the following

```
(add-to-roam-file-hooks #'my-func)
```